# gradle build error non zero exit value 3

Tags: android

Hi while compiling my project am getting an error message like this java.exe finished with non zero exit value

[image]

thank you in advance

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
compileSdkVersion 21
buildToolsVersion "22.0.1"

defaultConfig {
    applicationId "com.sentientit.theiWedplanner"
    minSdkVersion 9
    targetSdkVersion 21
    versionCode 13
    versionName "11.2"
    multiDexEnabled true

}

buildTypes {
    release {
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'
    }
    debug {
        debuggable true
        minifyEnabled false
        proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.txt'

    }
 }
}

dependencies {
compile 'com.android.support:support-v4:22.2.0'
compile 'joda-time:joda-time:2.4'
compile files('libs/bugsense-3.6.1.jar')
compile files('libs/core.jar')

compile files('libs/MtUtils.jar')
compile files('libs/socialauth-android-3.2.jar')
compile files('libs/universal-image-loader-1.6.1-with-src.jar')
compile files('libs/zxingjar-1.1.jar')
compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:7.5.0'
compile files('libs/ksoap2.jar')
compile 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.1'
compile files('libs/twitter4j.jar')
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I too was having this error after updating to the latest Android Studio.I fixed it by adding `multiDexEnabled true` in `build.gradle` within defaultConfig.

Example:

```
defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.stackoverflow.ranjith.androidprojdel"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 22
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
```

Comment: Post your build.gradle in your question..Its difficult to point the error without looking.